# Making a Discord rich presence browser extension using node.js and Browserify and i have trouble with Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, browserify, discord-rpc

Soo basically i made a Discord rich presence extension for when im on a specific site and I noticed i cant use node.js for it but if I use browserify I can work around that with a bundled script. The problem is that i get WebSocketTransport errors and i don't know how to solve those.
I have little experience with programming and i mostly create discord bots.
I am using discord-rpc node module because i have experience with it and Im only getting errors when i use the discord-rpc module.

Error:

```
bundle.js:3177 Uncaught (in promise) Error: connection closed
    at WebSocketTransport.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3177:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (bundle.js:2179:26)
    at WebSocketTransport.emit (bundle.js:2089:5)
    at WebSocketTransport.onClose (bundle.js:4147:10)

bundle.js:3166 Uncaught (in promise) Error: RPC_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
    at bundle.js:3166:47
```

The way i defined the module:

```
const clientId = '865555817466298408';
const RPC = require('discord-rpc');
const scopes = ['rpc', 'rpc.api', 'messages.read'];
const client = new RPC.Client({ transport: 'websocket' });
```

The Location of the error:

```
async connect() {
    const port = 6463 + (this.tries % 10);
    this.tries += 1;

    this.ws = new WebSocket(
      `ws://127.0.0.1:${port}/?v=1&client_id=${this.client.clientId}`,
      browser ? undefined : { origin: this.client.options.origin },
    );
    this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
    this.ws.onclose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.ws.onerror = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: This module has not been updated since 2020 and first thing you see on its project page is "This library has been deprecated in favor of Discord's GameSDK" it probably just donrst work anymore.

Comment: Made a quick script and the discord-rpc library works, I think there's something wrong with the websocket connecting, i think its cuz im in a browser and not in an actual client